# Html date value issue with Razor page

Tags: c#, html, .net-core, razor

I have a database where I store date validity while creating a new project.

I'm using the html date and set the value to the current time.

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Project.PermitDate" class="control-label">Date de délivrance du permis</label>
                    <input type="date" value="@Model.CurrentDate" id="ProjectDateInput" asp-for="Project.PermitDate" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Project.PermitDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                    <p>Date d'expiration(+5ans): <span id="ProjectDateShow"></span></p>
                </div>
```

And I'm doing the same if the user want to modify the date

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Project.PermitDate" class="control-label">Date de délivrance du permis</label>
                        <input type="date" value="@Model.Project.PermitDate" id="ProjectDateInput" asp-for="Project.PermitDate" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Project.PermitDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                        <p>Date de délivrance du permis: @Model.Project.PermitDate</p>
                        <p>Date de d'expiration(+5ans): @Model.Project.PermitDate</p>
                        <p>Date d'expiration(+5ans): <span id="ProjectDateShow"></span></p>
                    </div>
```

But there is a problem, there is no value inside the html date input.
[image: Date value not set]
So the user need to enter the date each time he want to modify the project. Even if he doesn't change the date because the input show jj / mm / aaaa (it's in french for yyyy / MM /dd)

Can some one know how to convert c# DateTime to a format for HTML and have the default value from the database ?
Thank you

---

All the Edit page HTML

```
<div>
    <a asp-page="./Projects" class="btn btn-danger">
        <i class="bi bi-backspace-fill"></i>
    </a>
</div>
<h1 class="text-center">Nouveau projet</h1>

<hr />
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center w-100 mt-5">
    <div class="w-75">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

            <div class="card mb-2 p-3">

                <h2 class="h3 text-center">Générale</h2>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Project.FolderReference" class="control-label">Numero de dossier</label>
                    <input asp-for="Project.FolderReference" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Project.FolderReference" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Project.Title" class="control-label">Titre</label>
                    <input asp-for="Project.Title" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Project.Title" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Project.Status" class="control-label">Statut</label>
                    <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" asp-for="Project.Status">
                        <option selected value="OnGoing">En cours</option>
                        <option value="Stopped">Arrêté</option>
                    </select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Project.Status" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Project.PermitDate" class="control-label">Date de délivrance du permis</label>
                    <input type="date" value="@Model.Project.PermitDate" id="ProjectDateInput" asp-for="Project.PermitDate" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Project.PermitDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                    <p>Date de délivrance du permis: @Model.Project.PermitDate</p>
                    <p>Date de d'expiration(+5ans): @Model.Project.PermitDate</p>
                    <p>Date d'expiration(+5ans): <span id="ProjectDateShow"></span></p>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Project.ProjectType" class="control-label">Type de projet</label>
                    <input asp-for="Project.ProjectType" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Project.ProjectType" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Project.LandRegistrer" class="control-label">Cadastre</label>
                    <input asp-for="Project.LandRegistrer" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Project.LandRegistrer" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>




                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Project.ProjectPhase" class="control-label">Phase du projet</label>

                    <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" asp-for="Project.ProjectPhase">
                        <option selected value="CP">CP (Création projet)</option>
                        <option value="CE">CE (Contrat transmis)</option>
                        <option value="CS">CS (Contrat signé)</option>
                        <option value="ES">ES (Esquisse)</option>
                        <option value="AP">AP (Avant projet)</option>
                        <option value="PU">PU (Permis urbanisme)</option>
                        <option value="PE">PE (Plan d'éxécution)</option>
                        <option value="AO">AO (Appel d'offre)</option>
                        <option value="CT">CT (Contrôle des travaux)</option>
                        <option value="RP">RP (Réception provisoire)</option>
                        <option value="PEB">PEB</option>
                        <option value="SAV">SAV</option>
                        <option value="END">END (Archivable)</option>
                    </select>

                    <span asp-validation-for="Project.ProjectPhase" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Project.BillPhase" class="control-label">Phase de facturation</label>
                    <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" asp-for="Project.BillPhase">
                        <option selected value="ES">ES (Esquisse)</option>
                        <option value="AP">AP (Avant projet)</option>
                        <option value="PU">PU (Permis urbanisme)</option>
                        <option value="PE">PE (Plan d'éxécution)</option>
                        <option value="AO">AO (Appel d'offre)</option>
                        <option value="CT">CT (Contrôle des travaux)</option>
                        <option value="RP">RP (Réception provisoire)</option>
                        <option value="PEB">PEB</option>
                    </select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Project.BillPhase" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Project.BillPhaseState" class="control-label">Phase de facturation</label>
                    <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" asp-for="Project.BillPhaseState">
                        <option selected value="Facturable">Facturable</option>
                        <option value="Emise">Facture émise</option>
                        <option value="Soldé">Facture soldé</option>
                    </select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Project.BillPhaseState" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="card mb-2 p-3">
                <h2 class="h3 text-center">Personnes responsable du projet</h2>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Project.Groupe" class="control-label">Groupe</label>
                    <input asp-for="Project.Groupe" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Project.Groupe" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Project.Person01" class="control-label">Archi Front</label>
                    <input asp-for="Project.Person01" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Project.Person01" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Project.Person02" class="control-label">Archi back 1</label>
                    <input asp-for="Project.Person02" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Project.Person02" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Project.Person03" class="control-label">Archi back 2</label>
                    <input asp-for="Project.Person03" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Project.Person03" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card mb-2 p-3">
                <h2 class="h3 text-center">Adresse</h2>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Project.Street" class="control-label">Adresse</label>
                    <input asp-for="Project.Street" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Project.Street" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Project.StreetNumber" class="control-label">Numéro</label>
                    <input asp-for="Project.StreetNumber" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Project.StreetNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Project.StreetBox" class="control-label">Boite</label>
                    <input asp-for="Project.StreetBox" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Project.StreetBox" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Project.ZipCode" class="control-label">Code Postal</label>
                    <input asp-for="Project.ZipCode" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Project.ZipCode" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Project.Locality" class="control-label">Localité</label>
                    <input asp-for="Project.Locality" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Project.Locality" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Project.Region" class="control-label">Région</label>
                    <input asp-for="Project.Region" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Project.Region" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Project.Country" class="control-label">Pays</label>
                    <input asp-for="Project.Country" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Project.Country" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mb-2 p-3">
                <h2 class="h3 text-center">Budget</h2>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Project.TotalBudget" class="control-label">Budget Total</label>
                    <input asp-for="Project.TotalBudget" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Project.TotalBudget" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Project.ConstructionBudget" class="control-label">Budget construction</label>
                    <input asp-for="Project.ConstructionBudget" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Project.ConstructionBudget" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Project.Fees" class="control-label">Honoraire</label>
                    <input asp-for="Project.Fees" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Project.Fees" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <p>Utilisateur assigné: @User.Identity.Name</p>
                <p>Date de création: @Model.CurrentDate </p>
            </div>

            <input asp-for="Project.CreationDate" type="hidden" />
            <input asp-for="Project.UserCreation" type="hidden" />
            <input asp-for="Project.ModificationDate" value="@Model.CurrentDate" type="hidden" />
            <input asp-for="Project.UserModification" value="@User.Identity.Name" type="hidden" />
            <input asp-for="Project.ProjectId"  type="hidden" />
            <input asp-for="Project.ClientId" type="hidden"/>


            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center w-100">
                <input type="submit" value="Modifier" class="btn btn-info w-25" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-page="./Projects" class="text-danger"><i class="bi bi-list"></i> Retour à la liste</a>
</div>
```

---

All the Edit page HTML.CS

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ArchiProjectManager.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;


namespace ArchiProjectManager.Pages.Users.Clients.Projects
{
    [Authorize]
    public class EditProjectModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ArchiProjectManager.Data.ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public EditProjectModel(ArchiProjectManager.Data.ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        [BindProperty]
        public ModelForProjects Project { get; set; }
        public DateTime CurrentDate = DateTime.Now;
        public DateTime permitDate{get; set;}


        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
        {
            if(id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            
            Project = await _context.ModelForProjects.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.ProjectId == id);
             

            
            

            if ((Project.UserCreation != User.Identity.Name) || (Project.UserModification != User.Identity.Name))
            {
                return RedirectToPage("/Users/AccessDenied");
            }


            if (Project == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Page();

        }



        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            _context.Attach(Project).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!ProjectExists(Project.ProjectId))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return RedirectToPage("./Projects");
        }

        private bool ProjectExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.ModelForProjects.Any(e => e.ProjectId == id);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, we just need to use `min` instead of `value`

`<input type="date" min="@PermitDateTimeFormatted" id="ProjectDateInput" asp-for="Project.PermitDate" class="form-control" />`